# All themes are not appearing in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, gnome, themes

I a using ubuntu 13.10 and I can not see all available themes in either 'Appearance' or 'unity-tweak tool' Though I have many theme in `/usr/share/themes' directory. I do not have`~/.themes` folder. Do I need to create that folder and link something.

[image: terminal]

[image: unitytweak]

[image: appearance]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those themes listed are not full environment themes. They only theme a small part of the system. Atlanta, Bright, Crux, and Esco, for example, are only Metacity themes. They do not have icons or GTK+ themes.

Ambiance, Radiance, and I think HighContrast in that list, are the only ones that would be full system themes, and thus, the only ones that would be displayed in the list in the Display properties.

Comment: thank you for your response. Is there any place where I can download some more full system themes.

Comment: @DK Bose, I was going to accept the answer but you can not accept it if it is less than 5 minute of posting time.